# Coldfusion and SVNKit Log

Tags: coldfusion, svnkit

I am trying to use SVNKit to get a Log of the SVN Entries in Coldfusion.  I downloaded the latest SVNKit jar files and threw them in the lib folder under WEB-INF/lib.

Here is my code that should return an Array Of Log Entries but this code is returning a Null Pointer exception in Coldfusion 9.0.2.

```
SVNURL = createObject('java','org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL').parseURIEncoded(svnurl);
drf = createObject("java","org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepositoryFactory");
drf.setup();

rf = drf.create(SVNURL);
SVNWCUtil = createObject("java","org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCUtil");
authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(user,pass);

rf.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

log = rf.log(JavaCast("String[]",[]),JavaCast("null",""),JavaCast("long",10),JavaCast("long",15),true,true);

rf.closeSession();
```

When running this code, I receive the following Error.

**The system has attempted to use an undefined value, which usually indicates a programming error, either in your code or some system code. 
Null Pointers are another name for undefined values.**

Which points to this line..

```
log = rf.log(JavaCast("String[]",[]),JavaCast("null",""),JavaCast("long",10),JavaCast("long",15),true,true);
```

I moved this same code over to Railo, and everything is running fine.  I just cannot see why ACF is choking on the log() method.

I was using the [Printing Out Repository History](http://wiki.svnkit.com/Printing_Out_Repository_History) example on the SVNKit Wiki to start me off.

Any suggestions on getting it to work in Adobe Coldfusion would be greatly appreciated.  I did not test on CF10.

Comment: Might be a JVM issue. Check the SVNKit JVM requirements against what CF9.0.2 is running on.

Comment: I haven't found where it lists the SVNKit JVM requirements, but I have swapped out the JRE CF is using and still get the error.

Comment: If you dump `rf`, does it show the method signature you are attempting to use?

Comment: Okay... looks like I needed to add a JavaCast("boolean",true)  to the last two arguments to make it work.  Yes, the rf contains the method sig...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't using the JavaCast("boolean",true) for the last two arguments in the log() function.  After that, everything worked fine.

Got to remember to check and use JavaCast()!

```
log = rf.log(JavaCast("String[]",[]),JavaCast("null",""),JavaCast("long",10),JavaCast("long",15),JavaCast("boolean",true),JavaCast("boolean",true));
```